# How can I type hint the arr.array specific type when used as a parameter?

Tags: python, type-hinting

```
import array as arr

arr.array('i')

useArray(a)
```

PyCharm does NOT like type hint arr.array('i)' as a parameter :

```
def useArray(self, pArrayParam: arr.array('i'):
```

PyCharm is okay with this:

```
def useArray(self, pArrayParam: arr.array):
```

BUT I would like to specify the parameter array type more explicitly (as an int in this case). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No.  `array('i')` is not a type.  The `i` is just a parameter.  The type is `array`.

Comment: MyPy seems fine with `arr.array[int]` — does PyCharm stop complaining if you do that?

Comment: PyCharm doesn't complain with arr.array[int], but on debugging I immediately get:

File "C:\program\circularBuffer.py", line 152, in CircularBuffer
    def read(self, pBuffer: arr.array[int], pOffset: int, pNumBytesToRead: int) -> int:

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable